# I'm confused with understanding Xcode 6.1 simulator versus assistant editor

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I created my game apps in Xcode 5.1.1. Yesterday i downloaded Xcode 6.1. I downloaded 6.1 because i also want to make my app on iPhone 6 and 6+. Why is it when i upload the simulator for all iOS 8 devices the simulator loads normally full screen as if i already made adjustments for the phone for it's 4.7inch and 5.5 inch when i haven't. However, in assistant editor storyboard preview under the 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch phones there is a HUGE empty space because i haven't yet started fitting my 4 inch game designs for iPhone 6. So since simulator already loads the iPhone 6 design perfectly does it mean i don't have to actually custom build a 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch screen?? I'm confused.

Comment: Try going to editor->Resolve Autolayout Issues->Update Frames

Comment: That's probably because the simulator runs your app in zoom mode. If you add a launchscreen for iPhone6 (which basically states that you intend to support the larger screen) my guess is that the simulator will reflect what you see on the assistant editor (the non-zoomed version)